# Android layout XML code

Tags: android, xml, layout

Can somebody plz post the xml layout code for this (have a look at the link), really don't get this done...
Thanks.

[image: http://img832.imageshack.us/img832/6589/layouthelp.jpg]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:background="@drawable/background" android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:orientation="vertical" android:baselineAligned="false">
<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/logo" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
<LinearLayout android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"><Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/Button02" android:layout_gravity="right" android:text="@+id/Button02"></Button>
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/Button03" android:text="@+id/Button03"></Button>
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/Button01" android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:text="@+id/Button01"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post what you have tired and then we can help you correct it!(Right now your just asking us to do your work (homework?) for you...

Comment: Well this is my xml file right now. The Buttons wont come down, but layout_gravity is set to bottom....

Comment: Have you considered trying DroidDraw.org? It is a great help for us XML noobs to get started.

Answer (score 7):

Try to use RelativeLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  >
 <RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     >
  <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/Button02"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/Button03"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button02"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Button02"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        >
    </Button>
 </RelativeLayout>
 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     >
 </ImageView>
```

Comment: Thank you, works! And works also without the second relative layout